# Finding which column matched a LIKE out of multiple LIKE clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

```
SELECT COUNT(news_id) AS count 
FROM fusion_news 
WHERE (news_subject LIKE '%новым%' || news_news LIKE '%новым%')
```

Is there a way I can use an alias or set some flag to see which column matched? Currently I'm just doing a manual check in PHP after my query is done for whether `news_news` or `news_subject` matched, but if possible is there a way I can flag this somehow through SQL alone?

Comment: Do a UNION between two SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just query it as a boolean. Mysql converts `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` when treated as a number, so you could just `sum` the boolean expressions in your `where` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(news_subject LIKE '%новым%') AS news_subject_num_matches, 
       SUM(news_news LIKE '%новым%') AS news_news_num_matches
FROM   fusion_news 
WHERE  (news_subject LIKE '%новым%' || news_news LIKE '%новым%')
```

Comment: is this "efficient", though? could it be costly doing `LIKE` multiple times on a large dataset?

Comment: It shouldn't be any slower (at least not in a noticeable way) from your original query, which already has the `like`s in the `where` clause. And it would most probably perform better than a solution with a `union` (which goes over the data twice), although this needs to be benchmarked.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, I swear adding it in caused the results to change.. Before it was 20 matches and now it's 1? http://dpaste.com/26KZY01 . Only change was the addition of the `SUM` in the SELECT. Note: I'm using PDO and binding params, as well as dealing with cyrillic characters.

Comment: Actually just removing the `SUM` made it return `0` or `1` and it works. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

You could use UNION .. consider:

```
Select count(1) as Count, "in News Subject" as Source
  from fusion_news
 where news_subject LIKE '%новым%'
UNION
Select count(1) as Count, "in News Body" as Source
  from fusion_news
 where news_news LIKE '%новым%'
```

Or, if you want the count broken down
    Select (
            Select count(1) as Count
              from fusion_news
              where news_subject LIKE '%новым%') as SubjectCount,
    Select (
            Select count(1) as Count
              from fusion_news
              where news_news LIKE '%новым%') as Content Count